# Selecting the first row in excel where a column value equals a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a excel sheet which displays the status of various products on my website throughout the day, along with the timestamp of the status as so:

```
| Timestamp               | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 |
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 25/03/2021 08:15:52.020 | 999       |           | 0         | 999       |
| 25/03/2021 08:15:53.000 | 0         | 101       | 0         |           |
| 25/03/2021 08:15:53.070 | 0         | 0         |           | 0         |
```

A status of 0 means a product is available, while blank cells/other numbers indicate a product is unavailable.

For each Product I would like to get the first timestamp for which the product is available (i.e. when the value in the cell is 0 for the first time, not non-0 or blank). The end result being something like this:

```
|           | Timestamp               |
|-----------|-------------------------|
| Product 1 | 25/03/2021 08:15:53.000 |
| Product 2 | 25/03/2021 08:15:53.070 |
| Product 3 | 25/03/2021 08:15:52.020 |
| Product 4 | 25/03/2021 08:15:53.070 |
```

Is this possible to do using pure excel functions? Or would I need to use some Python/Pandas to get my desired table? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `INDEX/MATCH`

Assuming your data is in `A1:E4`, for product 1, you would use

```
=INDEX($A2:$A4,MATCH(0, B2:B4,0))
```

(change `B2:B4` to `C2:C4` and so on for the other products)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @cybernetic's solution, the formula in you second sheet can look up the column it should use. So sheet2, B2 is (assuming Z product columns, and 100 rows):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0, INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$Z$100,,MATCH(A2, Sheet1!$B$1:$Z$1,0)),0))
```

Breaking it down, the first MATCH from the right looks up the product name and returns a column index 1 through 25 (relative to B - Z). The first INDEX from the right returns a column vector containing the status info for the current product. The second MATCH looks for the first occurrence of zero in this column vector and returns the row index. The second INDEX uses this final index to pick out the timestamp on that row.

EDIT: Better yet, assuming the order of the listed products in sheet 1 and 2 stays the say, you don't have to search (MATCH), but can simply use the row number of the product in sheet 2 as column index in sheet 1...

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0, INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$Z$100,,ROW()-2+1),0))
```

where ROW()-2+1 gives an index of 1, 2, 3, 4... starting at row 2.

Comment: Note this is useful if you have a large number of products and don't want to manually update the status column reference for each product.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **INDEX** and **XMATCH** function.

For Product 1 is `=INDEX(A2:E4;XMATCH(0;B2:B4);1)`.

Just change B2:B4 to C2:C4 and so on for other products.

[image]
[image]

Comment: According to his tags, he won't have the `XMATCH` function

Comment: Indeed, XMATCH is only for Office 365 users. The solution is identical to MATCH. I was hoping the advanced features of XMATCH could be used to cross find the range from the product name and then jump to the timestamp.